# Module 'tensorflow' has no '__version__' member pylint (no-member)

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, pylint

I've just installed Tensorflow and trying to print the version I have installed.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

When I get this 'error':

```
Module 'tensorflow' has no '__version__' member pylint (no-member)
```

I say error because it prints `2.0.0` to the terminal but VSCode still says there's an error in the file. I think it may be an issue with the linter but I've installed `pylint` which is what [TF recommends](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/contribute/code_style).

Any ideas on how to fix this error? I'd prefer to know what's causing it before I add the argument to disable errors like that one.

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31576) help, what is the version number?

Comment: Version is 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the way I was checking the version was incorrect. Taking [a look at the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/version) it should be:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.version.VERSION)
```